# how to add OR to ifeq?

Tags: makefile

I've got this line in a makefile:

```
ifeq ($(filter -O2,$(BUILD_CXXFLAGS)),)
SOME_VAR := ...
endif
```

I'd like to change it to filter both -O2 and -O3. What would that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many words to filter as you like:

```
$(filter -O2 -O3,$(BUILD_CXXFLAGS))
```